# Browser support for transparent SVG background image

Tags: svg

I would like to use a SVG image (created in Illustrator) as a background image. The image is transparent (it looks a little like a watermark). What is the browser support for transparent SVG images? I've looked at the Can I Use website and around the internet but can't find the answer.

SVG image support is good (around 96% for the UK) but is there less support for transparency in SVG images?

Here is my code:

```
background-image:url("../resources/transparent_circles.svg");
```

Comment: If SVG is supported, transparency is supported. Do you encounter a problem?

Comment: Brilliant - I wasn't sure if that was the case - thank you